# Confused in choosing でした or です in のは～だ grammar

Tags: grammar, tense, cleft-sentences

Which one is the correct one between the following 2 sentences? Are my English translations correct?

> A: 昨日食べたのは肉まん**です**。
>
> A': It **is** nikuman (steamed meat bun) that I ate yesterday.
>
> B: 昨日食べたのは肉まん**でした**。
>
> B': It **was** nikuman (steamed meat bun) that I ate yesterday.

Note: I am not a native speaker in both English and Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is the word order. The neutral order is “昨日肉まんを食べました”. By saying it in the order “昨日食べたのは肉まん[です/でした]”, you are already conveying a **contrastive** nuance. That is to say, you ate 肉まん and **not something else**.

です/でした tends to have implications on this contrastive nuance:

> 昨日食べたのは肉まん**です**。ラーメンではなくて。
> *It was nikuman that I ate yesterday. Not ramen.*
>
> 昨日食べたのは肉まん**でした**。ラーメンではなくて。
> ***It turns out** it was nikuman that I ate yesterday. Not ramen.*

Using `でした` can imply that you are overturning a previous belief or statement. You previously thought/said it was ramen, but it turned out to be nikuman.

So for example, these are the natural choices:

- 先に帰ってきたのはお父さん**です**。
  *It was my father who came home first.*
- お母さんが先に帰ってくるはずだったのに、先に帰ってきたのはお父さん**でした**。
  *My mother was supposed to come home first, but it turned out to be my father who came home first.*

Answer (score 3):

As Toshihiko wrote, both A and B are correct sentences in Japanese.  However, they are not always interchangeable.

For example, suppose that you ate nikuman yesterday, but today your coworker asked you:

> 昨日カレーまんを食べていましたよね。どこで買ったんですか?  *You were eating karēman (curry-flavored pork bun) yesterday.  Where did you buy it?*

You can say (A) いいえ、昨日食べたのは肉まんです in response, but it is strange to say (B) いいえ、昨日食べたのは肉まんでした.  It is hard for me to pinpoint why (B) sounds strange in this case, but I feel that (B) emphasizes the pastness of the event for no reason even though you are making a correction now.

Answer (score 1):

Both A and B in Japanese are correct, the same fact as A' in English. B' is incorrect English.
Do you want to know about English?

Comment: I edited the question to fix the English typo and focus on the Japanese :-)