# です　vs. でした　to describe something in the past

Tags: tense

I've read a sentence in a textbook:

> 私が昨日乗った飛行機は中国航空です。

I wonder whether the last です can be changed into でした:

> 私が昨日乗った飛行機は中国航空でした。

or which is better?

I have the question because we say "Yesterday was Sunday." =　昨日は日曜日でした。

So it follows logically "The plane I took yesterday was China Airlines." = 私が昨日乗った飛行機は中国航空でした。

Comment: This looks similar: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29300/43676

Answer (score 2):

English likes to have the tenses all agree with each other in a sentence but this is not a requirement in Japanese. The plane you *took* yesterday (昨日乗った), in the past, presumably still belongs currently to China Airlines, in the present.

That being said, I don't feel ending with でした is strictly wrong. I'll wait for a native speaker's opinion on that though.